# Why does my C++ program output this?

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class programming {
protected: int variable;
public:
           programming() {
                   cout << "In constructor\n";
                   input_value();
           }

           ~programming() {
                   cout << "In destructor\n";
                   output_value();
           }

           void input_value() {
                   cout << "In function input_value\n";
                   variable = 100;
           }

           void output_value() {
                   cout<< "Variable is "<< variable << "\n";
           }

           void onemorefunction() {
                   if(variable%2) {
                           cout << "Variable is odd\n";
                   }
                   else cout << "Variable is even\n";
           }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
        programming object;
        object.onemorefunction();
        return 0;
}
```

When the above program runs it outputs:

```
In constructor
In function input_value
Variable is even
In destructor
Variable is 100
```

I am new to C++ and I am having difficulty as to why it prints all those lines out. I would think it wouldn't print anything out since only the onemorefunction function is called and that's it. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: The destructor is always called when an object's lifetime ends. In this case `object`s lifetime ends when the program terminates

Comment: *What* part of the output is hard to understand? You do know the lifecycle of objects, and how they are *constructed* and *destructed*?

Comment: The right tool to solve such problems is your debugger. You should step through your code line-by-line *before* asking on Stack Overflow. For more help, please read [How to debug small programs (by Eric Lippert)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). At a minimum, you should [edit] your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example that reproduces your problem, along with the observations you made in the debugger.

Comment: Sorry I just started learning C++ 2 days ago, I will learn how to debug though, I am just not there yet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`programming object;` creates an object named `object` whose type is `programming`. Creating an object calls the constructor. That's why you get the first two lines of output. When the object goes out of scope at the closing `}` at the end of `main` the object gets destroyed, and that calls the destructor. That's why you get the last two lines of output. And the call to `onemorefunction` prints the middle line, because that's what the code in the function does.

Comment: Thank you for the step by step walk-through I understand it much better now

Answer (score 1):

The output of program is as it should be, The last two lines of output

```
In destructor
Variable is 100
```

is printed because the destructor is called at the end when the lifecycle of objects ends.